# Having error cannot read hash of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to have materializecss' tab on my homepage. To initialize it, i will have to use

```
$('ul.tabs').tabs();
```

After having that line after document is ready, the error appeared

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of undefined
```

Below are my code:

```
'use strict'

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('HomeController', HomeController);

HomeController.$inject = ['$rootScope','$scope'];

function HomeController($rootScope,$scope) { 
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = "Supreme Kinetic";
    $rootScope.home_default = true;
    vm.tab_menu =   [
                        {name:'Chair',disabled:'',active:'',id:'chair', icon:'event_seat'},
                        {name:'Electric Kettle',disabled:'',active:'active',id:'electric_kettle',icon:'opacity'},
                        {name:'Cutleries',disabled:'',active:'',id:'cutleries', icon:'card_travel'},
                        {name:'Reward',disabled:'disabled',active:'',id:'reward', icon:'redeem'}
                    ];

    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.tabs').tabs();
    });
}
```

home.html

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab col s3 {{tab.disabled}}" ng-repeat="tab in vm.tab_menu"><a class="{{tab.active}}" href="#{{tab.id}}"><i class="material-icons tab_icon">{{tab.icon}}</i><div class="tab_text">{{tab.name}}</div></a></li>
</ul>
<div ng-repeat="tab in vm.tab_menu" id="{{tab.id}}">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card col l3">
            {{tab.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have searched many solution on the way it should load by using  **angular.element(document).ready** and also **$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function()** but both are giving the same error. What have i done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix that worked for me. I added the following to my controller:

```
$scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function() {
  // run any jQuery
  angular.element('ul.tabs').tabs();
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it is not working still. This time no error but the line angular.element('ul.tabs').tabs(); is not initializing my tabs